# jQuery - execCommand("insertUnorderedList", false, null); - Different behavior with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
execCommand("insertUnorderedList", false, null);
```

toggles bullets in div-tags.

It works just fine. But with the Internet Explorer, when toggleing back to "no bullet", the text font becomes smaller. Why? What can I do to prevent that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem with IE and 1 day get my time.  This worked for me

```
 setTimeout(function(){ execCommand("insertUnorderedList", false, null); },100);
```